# How can I measure the similarity of sequential categorical data?

Tags: distance, similarity, categorical-data, sequential

My data is a series of timestamps for sent and received messages from conversations. I have my original data as well as a variant sequence that I've generated.

```
Original: S---R--S-R----S
Variant:  S-S--R--S-R--S----R
```

Where S and R are sent/received messages and - means no message was sent at that timestep.

I'm looking for a similarity/distance measure that captures the temporal distance as well as the categorical distance.

Further, I have more conversation data from different participants, a total of 5 conversation histories spanning 65000 time steps but only 275 sent/received messages in total, so pretty sparse data. This looks like this:

Original:

```
Conv with person 1: S---R--S-R----S--------------------
Conv with person 2: --------------------S---R--S-R----S
Conv with person 3: -----------------------------------
...
```

Variant:

```
Conv with person 1: ------------S---R--S-R----S--------
Conv with person 2: ---S---R--S-R----S-----------------
Conv with person 3: -----------------------------------
...
```

I'd like to have a distance measure for the global data as well as the individual conversations.

I tried Dynamic Time Warping to try capture the temporal distance of the data (converting S -> 1, R -> 2, - -> 0) but that didn't seem to work too well, algorithm was happy to match 1s and 2s. I've also considered using Levenshtein distance for the conversation data but I don't think it works very well with sparse data. For example:

```
Original: S-------------------R-S
Variant:  S-R-------------------S
```

This example would give a Levenshtein distance of 2 (2 replacement operations) as the shortest distance, but intuition says the distance should be much greater than that. Of course maybe that distance is accurate and I just don't know what I'm talking about, which is why I'm here.

I'm considering developing my own distance measure, perhaps separate measures for the global/local contexts, but I thought it would be worth leaving a question here while I work on that.

So to clarify my question: Are there more appropriate distance measures for this type of data? Either one that works for both contexts or one for each context.

Thanks